# Unit test BizTalk Schemas & Maps using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: unit-testing, schema, visual-studio-2019, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I have a requirement to unit test BizTalk Schemas & Maps using Visual Studio 2019.
We are now upgrading to BizTalk 2020 and working on few items to get this done.

I am following this document but could not find the unit test wizard as mentioned in steps 6 & 7

[Using the Unit Testing Feature with Schemas and Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/using-the-unit-testing-feature-with-schemas-and-maps) (learn.microsoft.com)

i.e I have created a new Unit test Project, but under the Test Menu, I could not see New test->Unit Test Wizard.

Am I missing something?

Can anyone provide information on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think MS Doc must be refreshed, there is no test unit wizard from Test menu.

you have to create a unit test project like any other type of projects:

[image]